# VBA Makro that tells u if there is a filter on

Tags: excel, vba

I asked Copilot for a makro that displays a message if there is a active filter in the workbook. The code looks good but when I tried it nothing happens.

This is the code:

```
Sub VisaFilterMeddelande()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim harFilter As Boolean
    Dim meddelande As String
    
    ' Loopa igenom alla blad i arbetsboken
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
            harFilter = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Skapa meddelandet baserat på om filter är aktiverade eller inte
    If harFilter Then
        meddelande = "Arbetsboken innehåller aktiva filter."
        ' Visa meddelandet
        MsgBox meddelande, vbInformation, "Filterkontroll"
    Else
        ' Visa inget meddelande om inga filter är aktiverade
    End If
End Sub
```

I suspect that the problem is the loop sequance

Comment: You did add an "Worksheet_Change" event on the sheet you want to track?

Comment: _when I tried it_ - how did you "try" it ?

Comment: According to AutofFlterMode documentation , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.autofiltermode?view=vsto-2017 This property indicates only whether filtering is enabled; it does not indicate whether any data is being filtered. To determine whether the worksheet is actively filtering data, use the FilterMode property.

Answer (score 0):

ThisWorkbook => ActiveWorkbook

```
Sub VisaFilterMeddelande()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim harFilter As Boolean
    Dim meddelande As String
    
    ' Loopa igenom alla blad i arbetsboken
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '<== Denna plats har förändrats
        If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
            harFilter = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Skapa meddelandet baserat på om filter är aktiverade eller inte
    If harFilter Then
        meddelande = "Arbetsboken innehåller aktiva filter."
        ' Visa meddelandet
        MsgBox meddelande, vbInformation, "Filterkontroll"
    Else
        ' Visa inget meddelande om inga filter är aktiverade
    End If
End Sub
```